# What are Vanilla objects in .NET?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection, object

I was reading [this article from MSDN on Dependency Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163739.aspx) and I saw a term in the article I didn't quite understand, to quote:

> There are several reasons to use containers in your application development. Containers provide the ability to **wrap vanilla objects** with a wealth of other services. This allows the objects to remain ignorant about certain infrastructure and plumbing details, like transactionality and role-based security. Oftentimes, the client code does not need to be aware of the container, so there is no real dependency on the container itself.
>
> These services can be configured declaratively, meaning they can be configured via some external means, including GUIs, XML files, property files, **or vanilla .NET-based attributes**.

I understand that 'vanilla' generally refers to something that's plain, but I don't exactly understand the meaning here.

What does vanilla refer to in .NET?

Comment: Any context? Maybe language or technology you are talking about?

Comment: @Shady - The above question doesnt convey any meaning at all without proper context, atleast to me.

Comment: maybe part of an ice-cream management application (SCNR)

Comment: It's not exactly P. language related (though I'd rather understand it in a .Net context).. Anyway, it's pretty much related to Dependency injection, DI containers, etc

Comment: @Shady: Putting the question in the context of a concrete quote would make it easier to make sure we answered the question appropriately.

Comment: Updated!! check the description now.. let me know if it gives enough context

Comment: @Shady: Well, it's still not as concrete as saying, "In article X, what does the author mean?" but it's better than it was.

Comment: Your link points to *this page*.

Comment: @George: Thanks for the extreme makeover :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some context would make the question a lot clearer, but usually it's used to indicate an ordinary object (or type) with no "special powers". For example, if a serialization scheme claims to work with "vanilla objects" then you shouldn't need to decorate it with extra attributes etc in order to serialize it. Likewise if an ORM works with vanilla types, it shouldn't need to implement a specific interface or anything like that.

EDIT: Okay, having seen the context, the above seems to be about right.

Another way of thinking about it is that you can write a type which can then be used by a framework *without the type knowing about the framework*. So *some* DI frameworks require you to decorate the types themselves to allow injection, whereas others don't. The latter frameworks are capable of working with "vanilla" types.

Comment: Updated!! Added article link!!

Comment: What about the "vanilla .NET-based attributes"? Or it's just a variation for the same thing..

Comment: @Shady: A variation - again, just attributes which in this case the CLR itself has no particular knowledge of. I'm not sure I'd have used that particular phrase, but I suspect that's what's meant.

Answer (score 1):

Really no idea... but from the meaning I would guess that it could be an instance of a class that just has a constructor and where you can read/write members with no other methods.
Often this kind of class is useful so may be someone found a name for it. For example (in C++) consider

```
struct P2d
{
    double x, y;
    P2d(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};
```

Comment: Updated!! Added article link!!